# Can't bind to 'ngFormModel' since it isn't a known native property, after update Angular2 rc3

Tags: angular, formbuilder

After update to rc3, ngFormModel not working

my html:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
    <select ngControl="syncTime" name="syncTime" [disabled]="!sync" class="form-   control">

    </select>
</form>
```

my .ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            syncTime: this.syncTime
        });
```

Answer (score 11):

ngFormModel is replaced with formGroup in RC3.

Please refer https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/d/1RIezQqE4aEhBRmArIAS1mRIZtWFf6JxN_7B4meyWK0Y/pub

Comment: Yes, it  is renamed but still exist in the documentation.